# Start Cygwin in $USERPROFILE in windows terminal (preview)

Tags: windows, cygwin

I'd like to start Cygwin using the new windows terminal in `$USERPROFILE`

```
{
"name": "Cygwin",
"commandline": "c:\\tools\\cygwin\\bin\\bash --login -i",
"icon": "c:\\tools\\cygwin\\Cygwin-Terminal.ico",
"startingDirectory": "c:\\tools\\cygwin\\bin"
}
```

works and start Cygwin in the cygwin default user directory.

I'd like to change it to start in my user directory.

```
"commandline": "c:\\tools\\cygwin\\bin\\bash --login -i -c 'cd `cygpath $USERPROFILE`'"
```

Answer (score 0):

add

```
cd $(cygpath -u $USERPROFILE)
```

at the end of in your `.profile`

Comment: Right, I'm aware that's possible, but my question is how to do it without modify my profile by launching it into that folder.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25768502)

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you wanted :

```
"commandline": "c:\\tools\\cygwin\\bin\\bash -c 'cd `cygpath $USERPROFILE`;exec bash --login -i'"
```

The idea is to spawn a new shell after changing directory.

`Update`

Can you try :

```
"commandline": "c:\\tools\\cygwin\\bin\\bash --login -i -c 'cd `cygpath $USERPROFILE`; bash'"
```

Comment: This leads to: 
/usr/bin/bash: cygpath: command not found
/usr/bin/bash: line 0: exec: bash: not found